# How to load multiple log4j xml files programatically in spring without using xml configuration

Tags: java

I tried using

```
Log4jConfigurer.initLogging(firstFile,6000);
Log4jConfigurer.initLogging(nextFile,6000);
```

but the second file overrides the configuration of first

Comment: Are you trying to initialize multiple log4j loggers in a single application? Or are you trying to have only one logger - in which case, what are you trying to achieve with multiple configuration files?

Comment: We are trying to use two different log4j files in single application, is there any spring configuration available or how can we do it programatically.

Answer (score 0):

Programatically, you can merge 2 or more XML files into a single XML, and load it into Log4j.

Also, Log4Configurer.initLogging() is deprecated, but there is another way:
- DOMConfigurator.configure(Element element);

Using JDom or some other library, you can load/parse your two XML files, merge them to get a single XML Element, and pass it to the above method.